# Excel Opening a New Excel When I Hit Enter

Tags: microsoft-excel

Sometimes when I've been working in Excel, it will open up another Excel file when I hit enter. I am not sure why it does this, but how do I stop it? I've noticed it happens in a few versions of Excel.

I am using Excel O365.

I am trying to type rows in a cell. When I hit enter to go into a new cell is when it happens.

Comment: There are potentially several reasons why this might occur. Not much way to tell from your short description. Can you be more descriptive? E.g. what are you doing? Where is the mouse on the Excel screen?  Thanks.

Comment: -Excel 2013+/Office365 New Excel windows shows templates & options, hitting Enter at that point tells it to start 'Blank workbook'. -Existing Excel window these hotkeys will open a new Excel worksheet: Alt+F, N, L (or Enter 3 times)

Comment: Based on @gregg, maybe your `Alt` key is sticking...

Comment: Edited my post, does that help?